# ScriptResource.axd not caching

Tags: asp.net

I have scriptresource.axd and webresource.axd files served with the following header but they never get cached:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Microsoft-IIS/5.1
Date: Mon, 27 Feb 2012 18:26:38 GMT
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
X-AspNet-Version: 2.0.50727
Set-Cookie: IBA.NET=186661E187AA166417707A7A51716853DE5E800748512185BCCABB5D30F53A3545B3B423D3E86040BDFFCB50BF8A73868CA9887F9A9A1AE6C13002DF548444EC9A2B79298078B0DE3094F3C1304181CAB8D41E77C41F707611C9232A0947BD30BB4B7ECCE64B5CB8AA46D720F980961DDA3065796FB5E3D4E6773391C85556D919C84C20B360950D0B7BED18F6D32A8EFEC0E5E5F2440CE6BF57CF64EF94773A76BD0A46053412DC43A44BC22D99F8D1C92604C9E89289E736B15348944C95B554F3CED4|-1; path=/
Cache-Control: public, no-cache="Set-Cookie"
Expires: Tue, 26 Feb 2013 18:26:38 GMT
Last-Modified: Fri, 24 Feb 2012 14:16:48 GMT
Content-Type: application/x-javascript
Content-Length: 84019
```

I am running the app with `<compilation debug="false">` and `<scriptResourceHandler enableCompression="true" enableCaching="true"/>` to no avail.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are the other content getting cached okay? How are you checking the above result? Fiddler? Is there a load balancer? If yes, do you have eTag set to the same value for all the servers?

Comment: @Sidebp Yes you have right, I search my code to find out what I have done but did not find yet...

Comment: @Rahul, other content is being cached. Checking using Fiddler. Production is load balanced but the issue (and snapshot above) is from my local dev PC.

Comment: @Sidebp Hmm strange. Tried all kinds of configurations but can't reproduce your problem. This guy is talking about enabling GZIP encoding and hiding 304s (in Fiddler) did the trick. - http://forums.asp.net/t/1127582.aspx